# What are some common problems that can occur when upgrading TestComplete 8.X to 9.0?

Tags: testcomplete8

I managed to convert the project suite and all projects successfully and they are still running. I want to use this thread to collect issues that might still arise to warn others.

Comment: I'm using TestComplete 8.x but may not upgrade for a while - depending on company budget. I'll be following this with interest and add my own experiences when I have something to add.

Comment: This is a question that cannot really be answered with a single answer. It needs to be be reworded so it can be answered, or be converted to community wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I found:

Advantages in comparison to 8.7

1. Own script debugger, no more Microsoft Script Debugger necessary
   which did not work on one computer, breakpoints were not hit
2. No longer crashing in double-clicking the log entries from within
   TestComplete until now

Disadvantages in comparison to 8.7

1. Drop-Down box for functions does not work always

Answer (score 0):

WaitNamedChild function failes to find windows unless a Sys.Refresh is executed first!